# How to set image path for jquery flip Counter Plugin

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm using Rails and want to implement FlipCounter. Here is link to documentation - http://bloggingsquared.com/jquery/flipcounter/ .

I think it is not showing because of image path. From documentation:

```
    Here's an example. This image is located at img/flipCounter-custom.png, each digit is 50 pixels wide and 67 pixels tall. I can use it as a flipCounter with the following code:
    $("#grunge_counter").flipCounter({imagePath:"img/flipCountercustom.png",digitHeight:67,digitWidth:50, number:244});
```

It is working in plain page with default path(**not Rails project**)

I put js files and put html code in my page.

Here is included files:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/counter.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/static_pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.easing.1.3.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.flipCounter.1.2.pack.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/static_pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and plain HTML:

```
     <div id="counter"><input type="hidden" name="counter-value" value="100" /></div>
```

and jQuery to call it:

```
            $("#counter").flipCounter();
```

but I need to use path something like:

```
   $("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath:"//some path//flipCountercustom.png"});
```

but I'm failing to set it. I'm even tried to create img directory in application.html.erb file.

**EDIT: TRIED VARIANTS**:

```
       $("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath: <%= image_path("flipCounter-medium.png") %> );

       -------

       $("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath: "<%= image_path("flipCounter-medium.png") %>" );

       -------

       $("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath: <%= image_path("/images/flipCounter-medium.png") %> );
```

**Image placed in assets/images folder**

Can someone suggest why it is happening ?

Comment: where is your flipCountercustom.png stored?

Comment: @PriteshJ , assets/images/flipCountercustom.png

Comment: does `yourserver/assets/flipCountercustom.png` returns it properly?

Comment: Also tried `$("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath:<%= asset_path("/images/flipCounter-medium.png") %>} );`not worked.

Comment: @PriteshJ, what do you mean ? I should write it in URL ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it - it is working. I do can see the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added it when your document loads

```
  $(function() {
    $("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath: "<%= image_path('flipCountercustom.png') %>"} );
  });
```

I tried and this worked for me.

if you want to use the url directly instead of image_tag use

```
 $(function() {
    $("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath: "/assets/flipCountercustom.png') %>"}           
 });
```

Comment: do you have `//= require_self` in application.js

Comment: Worked when I put it in my erb file! Thanks! It is not very Rubish at this moment.

Comment: Tried to put in application.js, but form ther it is not working. Maybe I should take image_path fuction off ?

Comment: I recommend not to add anything in application.js keep it just as an index, create a new file something.js.erb and add it there and include it in application.js

Comment: PriteshJ , thanks. Now I should think how to save counter value into database.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the assets pipeline is causing you grief.  The image_path helper (ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper) can fix you up,  try:

```
$("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath: <%= image_path("flipCountercustom.png") %>} );
```

Comment: @Brad, what you can suggest otherwise ?

Comment: look at the generated HTML,  what exactly is the path that image_path is returning,  and is the file really at that location?

Comment: @Brad , this is generated image path `imagePath:/assets/flipCounter-medium.png`

Comment: @MID , try `<%= image_path("flipCountercustom.png") %>` with double quotes `"<%= image_path("flipCountercustom.png") %>"`

Comment: @PriteshJ , this is generated path `$("#counter").flipCounter({imagePath: "/assets/flipCounter-medium.png" );`